# How to use MXML mx.controls.Label in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have one AS3 application which was developed entirely in AS3 without using single line of code in MXML. Of late I am realizing that MXML has some rich controls which are not provided in open source Apache Flex SDK. One library which is of most interest to me in mx.controls, it includes Label, DataGrid etc.

Now, I want to extend my AS3 application to call mxml compiled into swf file. I tried to import mx.controls inside my AS3 programs but it does not sense that. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong. If I am able to import mx.controls inside as3 class it would save me a lot of time. Can I do this?

Alternatively, I am trying to write a few applications in mxml and then call (.swf) in AS3. Is it possible?

I tried Googling but all examples are pointing to using ActionScript inside MXML with [CDATA[]]. But I want the inverse. Calling MXML from ActionScript.

Please explain me at nuts and bolts level as I am struggling with this a lot.

thanks in advace

Comment: Post some code that you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks Neal Davis, but that would not be necessary as Nemi has understood the problem and answered it. I just wanted someone to confirm me that I am not missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because Flex, that uses MXML, is framework built on top of the Actionscript. But you can do reverse. In Flex MXML you can use Actioscript code, and you can also use Flash components like `Sprite`, `MovieClip`... by using [`UIComponent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) or [`SpriteVisualElement`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html) as their parent container.

Comment: Nemi, thanks for your quick answer. I suspected that. There were some blogs which showed how to use mxml within ActionScript but it looked more a hack than a solution. But that leaves not much choice in ActionScript as there is no Label, Button or DataGrid.